# How to implement a piece of code in a class method?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a piece of code

```
if (a != b[i]){
 cout<<"Wrong!"<<endl;
}
else{
 cout<<"Correct!"<<endl;
 c+=1;
}
```

a,b,c are of integer datatypes.
and i want to implement this piece of code in a class method

```
bool classname::check(int a){
 // how do i write it here?
}
```

Comment: You can probably start with copy and paste... Assuming that `int b[]` and `int c` are members of `classname`. If it doesn't work and you get errors, this will be a good question to ask here (after googling of course)

Answer (score 0):

There’s nothing stopping you from putting that code directly into your class method, but best practice is to avoid *side-effects*; you only want to modify variables defined within the method or within the methods list of arguments, and then use the return value in the external context. There are plenty of exceptions to this rule, but here’s what I imagine you’re doing:

```cpp
// caller.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include “<path_to_headers>/classname.h”

using namespace std;

const int B_LEN = 4;
int b[B_LEN] = {0,1,2,3};
int c = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)) {
    int a;
    cout << “set a to integer value: “;
    cin >> a;
    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<B_LEN; i++) {
        if (classname::check(a,b[i])) { //pass a and b[i] as arguments since classname needs to work with them
            cout << “correct!” << endl;
            c++;
        }
        else {
            cout << “wrong!” << endl;
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

```cpp
//classname.cpp
#include “<path_to_headers>/classname.h”

bool classname::check(int a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bool classname::check(int a, int[] b, int i) {
    // how do i write it here?
    if (a != b[i]) {
        cout<<"Wrong!"<<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else {
        cout<<"Correct!"<<endl;
        c+=1;
        return true;
    }
}
```